# OO design for extracting information from existing Data Object

Tags: java, oop

My code receives instances of a class `X` which represents data of some sort. I need to "extract" some information from these objects, and I need to do this in several different classes in my code.

My first idea to achieve this was to create a "data extractor" class which has a public method `extractInfoFromX`, that takes an object of class `X` as a parameter and returns the corresponding information. this would be a static method as it would not depend on any state. And this class would never be instantiated. But I know this goes against the fundamental idea of OOP.

I don't want to "pollute" the general class `X` with a function that is only relevant for my very specific subtask. I also can't change the way that instances of `X` are created. What would be the best OOP practice to solve this problem?

Edit:
Additional background information as requested:
objects of class X represent C programs (in the form of control flow automata that implement the visitor pattern). In my code i need to find only a specific subset of functions declared in these programs. The only way to do this is by iteration over the automaton nodes (via visitor) and collecting the relevant ones. I need to filter by different criteria in different places, but some places also share the same criteria.  Defining one of these visitors takes about 35 lines of code.

Comment: I think your approach is quite correct

Comment: There are so many possible solutions here.

Comment: are you extracting the same piece of data (the data of the same structure) in different places?

Comment: I think the question is too vague to be answered in a constructive manner. Perhaps you can give us a little bit of an example of your code and maybe we can give you more useful advice.

Comment: As @ACV has stated your approach is correct.

Your external class could just be a ObjectHelper and maybe later you'll even find yourself expanding this class functionality. Whether you should create instances or not from that object is very dependent on the overall design of your solution: If your object is going to have a "state" (some set of values related to the extraction or treatment of your data) you should make it an instanciable class, if not just don't.

Comment: thanks @Miquel, ACV , i suppose i will indeed just go with this most simple solution.

Comment: @DudeDoesThings i'm not sure there is any code i could post that would make the issue much clearer. the "extraction" is just a visitor which checks some conditions of the visited structure and collects data accordingly.

Comment: @user3636325 - by collecting data you mean it does some mapping and returns the corresponding entitty to the input entity?

Comment: Maybe you can encapsulate the different criteria in `Predicate<T>` keeping the thing dry-er.

Comment: @StefanFischer Thanks. Sounds like a good idea.